# Is there a bug when using for loop with vectors?

Tags: c++, loops, vector, unsigned-integer, integer-arithmetic

The problem is that when i do "for(int i = 0; i < vector.size() - 1; i++)", it gives me a "vector subscript out of range" error. However if I put the vector.size() - 1 in a variable, it works. Is this a glitch or am I just missing something?

this works:

```
    int sizePos = positionsX.size() - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizePos; i++) {
        if (snake.getX() == positionsX[i] && snake.getY() == positionsY[i]) {
            gameOver = true;
            std::cout << as << std::endl;
            as++;
        }

        if (apple.getX() == positionsX[i] && apple.getY() == positionsY[i]) {
            apple.eat();
        }
    }
```

and this does not:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < positionsX.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (snake.getX() == positionsX[i] && snake.getY() == positionsY[i]) {
            gameOver = true;
            std::cout << as << std::endl;
            as++;
        }

        if (apple.getX() == positionsX[i] && apple.getY() == positionsY[i]) {
            apple.eat();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looping from 0 to `positionsX.size()-1` (exclusive) will skip the last element. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Paul Espina Though the code is not correct nevertheless what you mean by "does not work". What are you expecting and what is the result? Does not it work when the vector is empty or when the vector is too big?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not point out what means "does not work" that is in which case the code does not work.

Nevertheless answering your question

> Is there a bug when using for loop with vectors?

I'll say that the code indeed has bugs.

First of all the size of vectors is defined as unsigned integral type. The type `int` in general can not accomodate all values of the unsigned integral type.

In this expression

```
positionsX.size() - 1
```

there is used the arithmetic of unsigned integral types. That is the expression `positionsX.size() - 1` is converted to the unsigned integral type and will be equal to the maximum value for the type provided that `positionsX.size()` is equal to 0. That is the expression in fact evaluates as

```
static_cast<decltype( positionsX )::size_type>( positionsX.size() - 1 );
```

For example for an empty vector you can get the following result

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> positionsX;

    auto size = static_cast<decltype( positionsX )::size_type>( positionsX.size() - 1 );

    std::cout << size << '\n';
}
```

The console output is

```
18446744073709551615
```

In the first case when an intermediate variable is used

```
int sizePos = positionsX.size() - 1;
```

the result of the expression

```
positionsX.size() - 1
```

can be truncated to fit an object of type `int` and corresponding indices will be valid (though the range can be in whole invalid that is it can be less than the actual range).

Thus your problem is that you are using the type `int` instead of the original type

```
decltype( positionX )::size_type
```

Also the loops omit the last element of the vector.

The correct loop can look the following way

```
for (decltype( positionX )::size_type i = 0; i < positionsX.size(); i++) {
    //...
}
```

Or at least you should use the type size_t as the type of the variable `i` (though the first variant is more correct)

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < positionsX.size(); i++) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the thorough explanation, I understand it better now

Comment: This is a Vlad special! Why am I the only upvoter thus far?

Answer (score 7):

`positionsX.size()` is an `unsigned` type. If it's zero then subtracting 1 from it gives you the maximum value of the unsigned type due to *wrap-around* and the fact that the expression is evaluated in unsigned arithmetic!

Use

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i + 1 < positionsX.size(); i++) {
```

instead, nothing that this will always omit the final element in the vector. If you don't want that then drop the `+ 1`.

Comment: Are you trying to say that at some point in my code, the vector has a value of 0? that makes sense. I think i know where to look for that on my code, thank you.

Comment: @PaulEspina: That's exactly what I'm saying. Also, rather than subtracting one from one side of a conditional, add one to the other.

Comment: but wouldn't that make it skip the first element instead of the last?

Comment: @PaulEspina: No, because algebraically a - 1 < b is the same as a < b + 1.

Comment: yeah i get it now my mistake. i was thinking that i + 1 would make the starting index to 1 instead of 0 but it wouldnt

Answer (score 2):

If `positionsX` vector is empty, then `positionsX.size() - 1` evaluates to `size_t(-1)` which is a very big positive value.

When converted to `int`, as in your first snippet, that value would likely turn back into '-1'. And the loop body is skipped.

When used in comparision `i < positionsX.size() - 1`, the compiler converts `i` to unsigned `size_t` and the comparision yields true. The loop body is executed. And it attempts accessing `positionsX[0]` which isn't there...